# is this correct mysql syntax for alter table

Tags: mysql

```
Alter table users 
Add  
{ 

};
```

and if so how would i add all three of these columns

```
`user_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_location` tinytext,
`author_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Is Google down ... ;) lol.. I think its one of those rare occasion, when even Bing could step into Google's shoes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, you're not really doing yourself any favours by asking such as question, as you won't learn anything from an actual answer. (i.e.: Someone telling you the correct syntax won't help you learn.)

As such, what you should do is:

1. Look at the [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) syntax on MySQL.com
2. Make a copy of the table in question. (You can use a "`CREATE TABLE <new table name> LIKE <existing table name>;`" to do this and populate it by using a "`SELECT INTO <new table> FROM <old table>;`", etc. (Here's the [SELECT INTO syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).)
3. Try out your proposed ALTER TABLE on the **copy** to ensure it does what you want.
4. If it does (of indeed if it doesn't) you can use "`DROP TABLE <new table name>;`" to dispose of the newly created table.

By doing this, you'll learn as you go which is a lot more valuable in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD (
  `user_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_location` tinytext,
  `author_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ADD [COLUMN] (col_name column_definition,...)
```

So can't you just separate each one of the parameters with comma.

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD `user_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
ADD `user_location` tinytext,
ADD `author_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Add you can see from the link you could use After and first to order your columns.